# Ajax Preloader image for tabs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using the Jquery UI Tools Tab system and would like to know if its possible to add a nice loading effect for tab-switching?

This is the setup I have, excluding the cdn for the tabs. 
**HTML**

```
<ul id="frames">
<li><a href="#tab1">Articles</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Videos</a></li>
</ul>   

<div class="panes">
    <div id="tab1">
Tab one
</div>

<div id="tab2">
Tab two
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
$("#frames").tabs("div.panes > div");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#frames").tabs({

    spinner: '<img src='img_src.gif' />'

});
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716862/jquery-ui-tabs-spinner-background-image) question:

> Add `<span>&nbsp;</span>` within `<a></a>` for each tab. `&nbsp;` is
>   required for the spinner to properly appear and disappear.